# 91/5000 How to show dates between a range and show the number of records in that range using SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a report and it must look like this:
[image]

My inicial data is 2019/08/01 and my final data is Today.
I have to show every date between this two dates,  and then the amount of records. If there is no record, it must show zero.

So I tried:

```
    SELECT M2.[Date], COUNT(1) AS 'qtd'
            FROM [RM].[Mov] AS [m2]
            WHERE [m2].[TipMovId] = 1  
            AND ([m2].[DataExercicio] BETWEEN '2019-07-31' AND GETDATE()) 
            GROUP BY [m2].[DataPosse]

            SELECT m2.[Date], COUNT(1) AS 'qtd2'
            FROM [RM].[Mov] AS [m2]
            WHERE [m2].[TipMovId] = 4  
            AND ([m2].[DataExercicio] BETWEEN '2019-07-31' AND GETDATE()) 
            GROUP BY [m2].[DataExercicio]
```

And SQL returns me something like this:

[image]

How can I join the results and show all the dates in my period??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
 SELECT M2.[Date], 
     sum(case when [m2].[TipMovId] = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS 'qtd'
     sum(case when [m2].[TipMovId] = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS 'qtd2'
     sum(case when [m2].[TipMovId] = 3 then 1 else 0 end) AS 'qtd3'
     sum(case when [m2].[TipMovId] = 4 then 1 else 0 end) AS 'qtd4'
    FROM [RM].[Mov] AS [m2]
    WHERE  
    ([m2].[DataExercicio] BETWEEN '2019-07-31' AND GETDATE()) GROUP BY [m2].[Date]
```